# Unable to perform SetExtension on 'repeated inside extensions'

Tags: c++, json, boost, protocol-buffers

```
import "IpInterfaces.proto";
package IpInterfaces;

message DNSServerNames{
    repeated string dnsServers=11;//limited only to optional?
}
extend IpInterfaces.IpInterfaceAddress{ 
    optional DNSServerNames dnsServerNames=1000001;
}
```

Unable to perform SetExtension(dnsServers,value).
Is this supported or is it limited only to OPTIONAL? I get below error on VS2012

```
"Error no instance of the overloaded function matches the argument list"
```

And when i modify the Proto to

```
extend IpInterfaceAddress{
                repeated string dnsServers=1000000;
}
```

i get below error message:

```
error C2664: 'google::protobuf::internal::RepeatedStringTypeTraits::Get' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'const std::string' to 'int'
1>          No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Comment: Have you tried something like this?  `SetExtension(dnsServers, std::to_string(value))` Keep in mind that this requires at least C++-11.

Comment: Unfortunately cant use C++ 11 here.

Comment: can you use Boost? You can use `#include <boost/lexical_cast.h>` `SetExtension(dnsServers, boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(value))`.  In the case you can't use any of these you can still `#include <cstdlib>` and then you can use something like using `std::strtol()`, but for this function refer [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) ... and if you can't use C++-11 you shouldn't put it in the tag for C++-11.

Comment: Found a fix with some help by GPB guys, the correct way to use is 

`i->MutableExtension(dnsServerNames)->add_dnsservers("aaa");`